# CSS selector regex match start and end

Tags: html, css

let say I have elements with `title` attribute like following

```
<div title="custom-marker-awlr-tailrace bbu-l2"></div>
<div title="custom-marker-aws-tailrace btut"></div>
<div title="custom-marker-arr-tailrace sbu-l3"></div>
<div title="custom-marker-wqs-tailrace bbu-l2"></div>
<div title="custom-marker-wqs-tailrace bbu-l1"></div>
```

how do I select `div` with title `custom-marker-wqs-tailrace bbu-l2` using CSS regex selector?

something like `div[title*="customer-marker-wqs...???"]` I don't know what should I write in place of ???

Comment: There is no such thing as a "CSS regex selector." The attribute selector allows "starts with" / "ends with" and similar selections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a single attribute selector, e.g.

```
div[title="custom-marker-wqs-tailrace bbu-l2"] {
  ...
}
```

so you match the exact string or you could chain two attribute selectors, e.g.

```
div[title^="custom-marker-wqs-tailrace"][title$="bbu-l2"] {
   ...
}
```

by selecting a title starting (`^=`) with `custom-marker-wqs-tailrace` and ending (`$=`) with `bbu-l2`

Comment: thank you very much, this selector `div[title^="custom-marker-wqs-tailrace"][title$="bbu-l2"]` saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors
But you're very close:

```
startsWith: div[title^="customer-marker-wqs"]
endsWith:   div[title$="customer-marker-wqs"]
contains:   div[title*="customer-marker-wqs"]
```